# Hibernate custom type autoregistration

Tags: java, hibernate

What is the simplest way to autoregister a custom type in Hibernate 4?

Stackoverflow forces me to make this question longer so I will add some detail:

I want it to work the way Jadira custom user types works, without annotating Entities, but for my own type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Jadira's scaffolding for this.

You can subclass AbstractUserTypeHibernateIntegrator from Jadira, and register your Integrator in META-INF/services/org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator in your Jar.

Disclaimer: I maintain Jadira.